# Type inference weirdness in Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, lambda, eclipse-neon

Good morning everybody,

I've struggled for some time understanding why the following piece of code doesn't compile in Eclipse Neon (JDT 3.12.3.v20170301-0400) but compiles perfectly with javac or Eclipse Mars:

```
public class TestLambda {

    protected static <K, V> Map<K, V> newMap(final Function<K, V> loader) {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    private final Map<Integer, Integer> working = newMap(key -> {

        final List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        final String[] array = strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
        foo(array);

        return null;
    });

    private final Map<Void, Void> notWorking = newMap(key -> {

        final List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        // This line seems to be the root of all evils
        foo(strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]));

        return null;
    });

    private void foo(final String[] x) {}

    private void foo(final Integer[] x) {}

}
```

The Eclipse compiler says "Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Map<Object,Object>` to `Map<Void,Void>`".

It seems that it cannot know which foo method must be called...

Do I do something wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I'm confused: which line does the error occur on? The one you highlight doesn't use map at all. And what's the `foo(Integer[])` for?

Comment: I know, Map is not used in the problematic code. Simply load this piece of code in your Eclipse Neon and see what happens...

Comment: This actual piece of code doesn't do anything usefull or even sensible at all... It's simply a stripped down version of other code that tries to illustrate and isolate the problematic behavior

Comment: Are you saying that the `foo(Integer [])` overload has to be there to display this behaviour? If not, you should strip that out too. (I am on my phone atm).

Comment: Yes it has to be there...

Comment: If Map isn't used in the problematic code, why is it used here?

Comment: @ntlind: this particular combination of generics and overloads triggers a behavior in the compiler that I cannot understand. I have actual production code that does use Map and all, but I show here only a stripped down version of it...

Comment: I don’t see any way how this could reasonably trigger such an error. By the way, regarding your way of using `toArray`, I recommend reading [this article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/)…

Comment: @Holger I don't see neither... but please just load this piece of code in Eclipse Neon and see what happens. I suspect a bug in Eclipse but my experience teached me that in 99% of the cases the error lied in the hands of the programmer (me)... That's why I'm searching for an explanation here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem even with the newest version, Eclipse Oxygen. The problem does not occur with any `javac` version of Java 8 or Java 9 beta.

We can clearly conclude that this is a bug and a weird one.

First, there is no ambiguity here. Both invocations of `foo` have to end up at `foo(String[])` and, in fact, Eclipse doesn’t report an ambiguity problem.

Second, the `foo` invocation has no impact on the functional type of this lambda expression.

If we change the line `foo(strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]));` to `foo(strings.toArray());`, we will get a real error at `foo` as no `foo(Object[])` exist, but the type inference will correctly resolve `Function<Void, Void>` for the lambda expression and `Map<Void, Void>` as `newMap`’s return type.

We could also create a real ambiguity problem by changing the `foo` declarations to

```
private void foo(final Serializable[] x) {}
private void foo(final CharSequence[] x) {}
```

This will cause an error on both `foo` invocations, as `String[]` is compatible with both methods and there is no relationship between `Serializable` and `CharSequence`, but the type inference for the `newMap` invocation is unaffected and resolves to
`<Void, Void> Map<Void, Void> newMap(Function<Void, Void>)` as expected.

The weirdest thing is, just swapping the order of the `foo` methods makes the error go away:

```
public class TestLambda {

    protected static <K, V> Map<K, V> newMap(final Function<K, V> loader) {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    private final Map<Integer, Integer> working = newMap(key -> {

        final List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        final String[] array = strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
        foo(array);

        return null;
    });

    private final Map<Void, Void> notWorking = newMap(key -> {

        final List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        // This line seems to be the root of all evils
        foo(strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]));

        return null;
    });

    private void foo(final Integer[] x) {}
    private void foo(final String[] x) {}
}
```

compiles fine.

There is a pattern behind it. You can have as many `foo` overloads you want, as long as the last declared one is *applicable* to the `foo` invocation. It doesn’t have to be the most specific one that is finally invoked, e.g. placing another `private void foo(final Object[] x) {}` at the end of the class will also solve the issue.

That pattern surely has no matching Java language rule…

Comment: Thanks for your research and your conclusion... In my production code, the "foo" method is on another class... I'm going to see if changing its position solves the problem. I will definitely file a bug.

Comment: I changed my production code and moved the invoked method so that it's in the last position and it compiles like a charm :-)